# Deleting style elements from a style in Delphi Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

For the life of me, i can't seem to figure out how to delete primitive or control elements from a style with in the style designer of Delphi. What am I missing? I have tried right clicking everything i could find and no option surfaces. I tried looking for a panel that isn't enabled. Can't seem to find one.  As of now, I have to edit the actual text and reload it, in order to delete a style element.

Delphi XE6

[image]

Delphi 10.1 Berlin

[image]

***EDIT UPDATE:
How do I get this window to appear in either IDE?***

[image]

EDIT UPDATE:
Looks like there is a very small button on top left of structure pane that does the trick. I will leave question open for someone to answer with any other way. If no one can, Ill post the answer and accept it.

[image]

Comment: Turns out, there is a button/ Glypth (albiet very small), at the top left side of the Structure Pane. When a style element is selected, it becomes enabled and you can click it to delete that element.

Comment: Thanks John for turning attention to the delete button. You are right about the Edit menu in XE4 to XE7, but in Berlin it exists. I corrected the answer for future readers convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To delete a style element (tested on Delphi 10.1 Berlin)**

- Right-Click the element in the *Structure view* to get a popup menu.
- Select *Edit - Delete*

[image]

Or use the button (doc with red X) immediately above the structure tree.

Thanks to John, I can confirm that in XE4 .. XE7 the popup menu doesn't have the *Edit* menu, so the only means left is the delete button, mentioned above.

The third image (in your edit) is not familiar. Where did you get the image? Perhaps a third party style editor. Possibly not intended to be incorporated in the IDE.

Comment: All i get in my popup menu is Stay On Top and Dockable

Comment: The third image was from an earlier version of Delphi. I believe it was XE3.

Comment: ahhh, you are correct! I was testing it in XE6 the last comment I made. In 10.1 Berlin it is there. Thanks!